# vector.h in dll not useable in my application

Tags: c++, vector, dll

I'm new here...and I have a problem in my application.
I have written a dll, in which i use a struct and a vector. In the vector i want put my struct instances. So far it's everything fine.

The dll ist imported in my application. And now i want to use the vector of my dll also in the application, but this doesn't work.

I don't get any errors, what i want to do is to get the information in my main()-Application for example in this way:

```
#include "lib.h"
#include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        char setData[4];
        setData[0] = 0xBE;
        setData[1] = 0x3E;
        setData[2] = 0xB8;
        setData[3] = 0x13;

        getuseablePID(setData);     //this function is in my dll and copies the information of my csv-Data to my vector

        //here i want to know the size of my vector an want to print one element but this doesn't work 
        int a = globals::getInstance()._csvContent.size();
        cout << globals::getInstance()._csvContent.PID;

        return 0;
    }
```

and here is my dll-Code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)



struct csvDatei_Para {
    string PID;
    string Beschreibung;
    string Byteanzahl;
    string Min;
    string Max;
    string Einheit;
    string Wertetab;
};

struct globals {
    static globals& getInstance()
    {
        static globals instance;
        return instance;
    }
    std::vector<csvDatei_Para> _csvContent;
};
```

I also tried this way:

```
EXPORT struct globals {
    static globals& getInstance()
    {
        static globals instance;
        return instance;
    }
    std::vector<csvDatei_Para> _csvContent;
};
```

Does anybody know, why it's not working and give me a solution?

Thanks :)

Comment: it doesn't work?

Comment: You don't appear to actually be exporting any of the objects. You #define EXPORT, but don't actually place it in front of the objects that I assume you want to export.
Though, it would also help if you mentioned what error(s) you're getting.

Comment: add the error code also, it helps to go through the question easily

Comment: i did an update of my question, maybe now it's easier to understand what i want to do

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Now I got a solution.

I wrote a function, which returns an instance of globals.
This instance I can use to get the variables of my struct.

in my .h:

```
EXPORT struct globals getValues();
```

in my .cpp:

```
struct globals getValues(){
return globals::getInstance();
}
```

in my Application:

```
getValues()._csvContent.PID;
```

Comment: This should be an edit to the question rather than an answer as you're not answering the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Please test this code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#ifndef GUARD_DLLHDR_H
#define GUARD_DLLHDR_H

#if defined(BUILD_MY_DLL)
#define DLLSYM __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLSYM __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

    struct csvDatei_Para
    {
        string PID;
        string Beschreibung;
        string Byteanzahl;
        string Min;
        string Max;
        string Einheit;
        string Wertetab;
    };


    struct globals {
        static globals& getInstance()
        {
            static globals instance;
            return instance;
        }
        std::vector<csvDatei_Para> _csvContent;
    };
    DLLSYM extern globals myGlobals;

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: thanks for your example code; but now i don't know how get the information... i tried "myGlobals._csvContent.size()" an i get the errors LNK2001 and LNK1120